# How to create responsive web page using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, responsive-design, angularjs-scope, angular

Please provide me the links or any suggestion regarding the creating responsive web page using angular JS.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please check the help menu about what to ask and what not to ask and how to ask good questions.

Comment: Responsive has nothing to do with angular

Comment: Ho ho ..... When did responsiveness changed hands from Bootstrap, Foundation, Pure, MD to Angular? Lolz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best and broadly used : **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**.
  For nice look,feel & components : **[ng2-material](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material), [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html)** 
.

Comment: If I use Angular 1, would Twitter Boostrap be the best option for responsive design? I am thinking using Boostrap's css parts only to just achieve responsive design goal, no js parts involved. I heard Boostrap's js code is somehow not compatible with Angular's js code.

Comment: Bootstrap contains mainly two things. (1)Css/class to make responsive design and for feel & look  (2)Components. Css/class is something which can be used with HTML tags. If you plan to use `Bootstrap.js` then yes they are not fully compatible with Angular1 instead you can use `Ui Bootstrap`which is made for Angular1.

Comment: The ng2-bootstrap link isn`t working

Answer (score 0):

To make your task more easier instead of using the bootstrap jquery file use **angular's ui-bootstrap directives** (to be free from compatibility issues). Here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: FYI...ui-boostrap only provides components which are compatible with `Angular1` (not with `Angular2`) For angular2 `ng2-bootstrap` is there....

Comment: Thank you @micronyks for the info!

Comment: you're welcome @Mohit